# Use JMX html adapter with Apache Camel JMX

Tags: java, html, adapter, apache-camel, jmx

I am trying to use the Sun HTML JMX Adapter for showing the JMX beans that Camel exposes in HTML format. I am doing it using Spring XML but I am not able to figure out how to connect the adapter to the JMX agent. Could somebody help me?

Comment: If you want a web console to see JMX MBeans, Camel stuff, etc. then take a look at http://hawt.io/ - as it has all that out of the box.

Comment: I have just installed it and it's great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Claus Ibsen has suggested, hawt.io is a great tool to do that. Also, it took me 1 minute to download it and get it running. Totally recommended: http://hawt.io/